# How to Query a prepared statement in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, find

I have a prepared statement and needs to query it using find() in cakephp 1.3.. How would i do it. i tried different conditions but with no success. Here's my prepared statement

```
"select v.id from vehicles as v left join trips t on (v.id=t.vehicle_id) where t.departure_date between '2012-10-31 10:41:30' AND '2012-11-06 10:41:38' and t.id is null"
```

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt you actually need a prepared statement for this, because you can perform this query using 'regular' find syntax in CakePHP, however it *should* be possible; http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#prepared-statements

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this sql statement will ever return any results since you are saying t.departure_date between certain values and then saying t.id IS NULL (unless t.id can actually be NULL in the table).  Presumably, you want something like this:

```
select v.id 
from vehicles as v 
    left join trips t on v.id=t.vehicle_id 
        AND t.departure_date between '2012-10-31 10:41:30'
            AND '2012-11-06 10:41:38' 
WHERE t.id is null
```

This will return any vehicle id that does not exist in the trips table for those departure dates.  As far as the php side goes, not sure I can help with that.

Hope this helps.